# Access Properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

In use of the qooxdoo framework, in a class:
(in the .xml file activeRow is defined as an object_iterate: )

```
        <object_literal name="activeRow" scope="static" constructor="false" deprecated="false" private="false" protected="false" ignored="true" internal="false" type="Object">
            <property name="nullable" scope="static" constructor="false" deprecated="false" private="false" protected="false" ignored="true" internal="false" type="Boolean">
            </property>
            <property name="check" scope="static" constructor="false" deprecated="false" private="false" protected="false" ignored="true" internal="false" type="String">
            </property>
        </object_literal>
```

this DOES work:

```
properties: {
        activeRow: {            
            nullable: true,
            check: "Object"
        },
...

this.setActiveRow(123);
var x = this.getActiveRow();
```

this DOES NOT work:

```
properties: {
        activeRow: {            
            nullable: true,
            check: "Object",
        init: {test1: null, test2: null}
        },
...

this.setActiveRow({test1: 123, test2: 123 });
var y = this.getActiveRow().test1;
```

Does anyone know which part of the syntax is wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Addition containing discussion below:

alert(typeof this.getActiveRow); returns: function

alert(this.getActiveRow);

returns:

```
function(){
return qx.core.Property.executeOptimizedGetter(this, bI, name, "get");
}
```

Comment: The last comma should be removed -> check: "Object",

Comment: ahgood is correct in the first example that there are too many commas. However, you state that the first example is working. It is not possible to tell what's wrong based on your limited code pastes. We cannot see what setActiveRow and getActiveRow actually do and/or return. We also cannot see in what scope they're defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this more complete [Playground example](http://tinyurl.com/66crg63) (where you can also experiment with the code). Here is the code itself:

```
qx.Class.define("Foo", {
    extend: qx.core.Object,
    properties: {
      activeRow: {
        nullable : true,
        check: "Object"
      },
      activeRowInit: {
        nullable : true,
        check: "Object",
        init: {test1: null, test2: null}
      }
    },
    members : {
      setAndGet : function () {
        this.setActiveRow({a:1,b:2});
        /*this.setActiveRow(123);*/
        var x = this.getActiveRow();
        return x;
      },
      setAndGetMember : function () {
        this.setActiveRowInit({test1: 123, test2: 123 });
        var y = this.getActiveRowInit().test1;
        return y;
      }
    }
});
var f = new Foo();
alert(f.setAndGet());
alert(f.setAndGetMember());
```

It captures your code snippets, with a property with and one without 'init', and with getting the whole property, or just a member of the property's object. For me, it all works as expected. If you use `this.setActiveRow(123)` in the "setAndGet" method, you get a reasonable error message saying something like "expected value of type object but got 123" (in the log pane).

Comment: problem solved: I had to pass the context, as you said the get and set worked well itself.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the first sample works it means `setActiveRow` method is expecting an integer as its argument, so probably passing the associative array `{test1: 123, test2: 123 }` is breaking it.

So have such code as you have in the first sample:

```
this.setActiveRow(123);
```

Then the second line should work fine assuming `test1` is property of the class.

Comment: Qooxdoo does automatically build a set- and get for it,-which I could not find anywhere. It is just defined in the .xml-file as edited above, and than as property in the js class.

Comment: @N47 ok, what you mean exactly by "this DOES NOT work"? What happens? You get error?

Comment: I wanted to use this to carry two- instead of one data entries with this object.. my other solution would be an array which i fill in the object, but I thought this would not be the way its ment to be used.

Comment: @ shadow Wizard, firebug tells me "getActiveRow is not a function" when i run the site containing the script.

Comment: @N47 but you said "this DOES work" on your first sample that also contain `getActiveRow` call - so I'm bit confused here.. EDIT: in case of syntax error somewhere, the whole script block won't be loaded - you should see this in Firebug as well.

Comment: yes, i also don't understand.. first sample works, second not. It is an exception, that says "getActiveRow is not a function. I think I haven't understood the relation.. so you this {test1: 123.. } is an assoziative array- i thought these are fields of the object.. I am a bit confused right now.

Comment: I've just read:   

So we have to use one of JavaScript's minor mysteries. In JavaScript, objects are also associative arrays (or hashes). That is, the property

theStatus.Home

can also be read or written by calling

theStatus['Home']
.
And now I think about, if activeRow automatically gets get- and set by the Qooxdoo SDK, so that you can use it like var xyz = this.getActiveRow(); - can I really use it for my purpose? Maybe its this.getActiveRow.test1, without '()', the error message stays out this way, but the value is "undefined" than..

Comment: @N47 unfortunately I'm not familiar with qooxdoo, but from what I did see what you said is correct, it's adding "getter" and "setter" functions by itself. To move on try running this: `alert(typeof this.getActiveRow); alert(this.getActiveRow);` - what do you see in the alerts? Knowing the type might shed some light..

Comment: Thanks for this, sounds  like a plan! I'll be able to try this out next at beginning of next week!

Comment: @N47 wow long weekend you have there.... (I'm just *little* jealous :)) - good luck, keep me updated. :)

Comment: back right now, I was I'll- not long weekend.. :P

Posted the result above! I think the problem is in the context, and the syntax here is right! So thank you for suggestions, but don't waste your time on this anymore cause I think I missinterpreted the error message.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, the first answear itselft was not the right one, but you helped me finding it :)